# SQL Server database will not update info from website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have just started Web Development in C#, so I am fairly new. I am trying to do a basic "Register new users code" I am referencing a stored procedure that I have saved in SQL Server , and everything seems to be fine. But as I am very new to web development, I'm not sure if I'm missing something. The problem is the database will not update. I run the application and enter the info, after the clicking the button, I refresh the database, but it doesn't insert. Pretty sure the stored procedure is working fine... query test works.

C#:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Account
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PracticeConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertUser", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Email.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password.Text;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Asp.Net:

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Account.Register" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PracticeConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [User]" InsertCommand="InsertUser" 
        InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <table style="font-size:100%;width:388px;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    Sign Up for Your New Account</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                        ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                        AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                        ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                        ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                        ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." 
                        ToolTip="Security question is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." 
                        ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                        ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                        Display="Dynamic" 
                        ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
                        ValidationGroup="RegisterUser"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="OnClick" Text="Create User" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: How do you check that the update has failed? Looking at your database using Server Explorer in VS IDE?

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like?

Comment: @Steve...sorry abotu that...i got it...i just forget to refresh went back and did so and it is working fine

Comment: If it all works properly, please delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way to add your parameters: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", UserName.Text));`